# The value no update , when using click event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why the value won't change, when I use click Event?

```
public class Custom : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int saveindex;

    public void Oneclick(int buttonindex)
    {
    saveindex = buttonindex;
    Debug.Log(saveindex);  // Show buttonindex
    }

    public void Twoclick(int buttonindex)
    {
    Debug.Log(saveindex);   // Show 0
    }
}
```

and the inspector still show saveindex = 0; why

Comment: Oneclick & Twoclick isn't events, they are just 2 methods.

Comment: See 'Messages' list for the sorts of events a MonoBehaviour will react to; https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [KiynL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5740243/kiynl) said, both aren't events, they're methods.
If you want to make something happen when you click or double click on some component, you have to select this component (*Button, textBox, comboBox...*) and go on to:

> View > Properties > *A yellow lightning button, there you'll have the possible events for the selected component*.

Double click on the empty small textbox beside the event name and the **method** will be autogenerated, there is where you'll put your code.

This is a example of the event list (Photo - Imgur):

[Events list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZCqt.png)